# overriding OnActionExecuting as async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a Controller which has OnActionExecuting overridden as async method, this way:

```
protected override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
}
```

Inside that method I am calling some awaitable methods, such as

```
await db.Empresa.FindAsync(EmpresaID);
```

and

```
await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

With that, I am receiving the error:

> ASP.NET Controller: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

Is it possible to make `OnActionExecuting` method as async? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Side note: ASP.NET Core does support asynchronous action filters.

Answer (score 2):

No, it returns `void` not `Task` or another awaitable type, so the calling code won't be able to determine when the asynchronous work has completed.

If you must use an asynchronous method within `OnActionExecuting` (and it doesn't appear as though you do, because Entity Framework has synchronous equivalents) there are only sub-optimal workarounds available.

You will need to block the current thread, but you need to be careful that you don't cause a deadlock due to ASP.NET's synchronisation context.

One option is to run the asynchronous code on the thread pool:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => db.Empresa.FindAsync(EmpresaID));
    var result = task.Result;
}
```

This would actually be less efficient than simply using `db.Empresa.Find(EmpresaID)`, as there is overhead associated with `Task.Run`.

Comment: I have finally replaced all async calls to the sync counterparts in EF.